# xUnit : Mutiple Assertions or Soft Assert

Tags: c#, specflow, xunit

How can I find Multiple Assertions or Soft Assert in xUnit?  I found Nunit has below ability, trying to find similar options in xUnit.

```
Assert.Multiple(() =>
 {
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult1, actualResult1, "Mismatch in Score1!");
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult2, actualResult2, "Mismatch in Score2!");
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult3, actualResult3, "Mismatch in Score3!");
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of xUnit 2, it [does not exist](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1377).

> There are plenty of things we could do, but for many reasons we choose not to. This reasons include: (a) implementation and maintenance cost; (b) competing priorities; (c) philosophical objections to features.
>
> In this case, you're running afoul of (c). We do not believe that a ***unit testing framework*** should ever run more than one failing assertion.

xUnit is in general much more opinionated than NUnit, and won't include things which NUnit supports, for ideological reasons.

---

It [looks like xUnit 3 will support this](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1377#issuecomment-905888105), using `Assert.Multiple`.

Answer (score 3):

Put your test cases into an `IEnumerable<T>` and use `Assert.All<T>()`:

```
var expectations = new List<Tuple<object, object>>()
{
    new(expectedResult1, actualResult1),
    new(expectedResult2, actualResult2),
    new(expectedResult3, actualResult3),
};
Assert.All(expectations, pair => Assert.Equal(pair.Item1, pair.Item2));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like assertions in a BDD / fluent style, you may consider using one of these libraries, both fully compatible with xUnit:

- [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) offers soft assertions via [Assertions Scopes](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#assertion-scopes):

```cs
using (new AssertionScope())
{
   actualResult1.Should().Be(expectedResult1, "Mismatch in Score1!");
   actualResult2.Should().Be(expectedResult2, "Mismatch in Score2!");
}
```

- [Shouldly](https://docs.shouldly.io/) offers soft assertions via [ShouldSatisfyAllConditions()](https://docs.shouldly.io/documentation/satisfyallconditions) method when dealing with an object:

```cs
var mrBurns = new Person { Name = null };
mrBurns.ShouldSatisfyAllConditions(
   () => mrBurns.Name.ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty(),
   () => mrBurns.Name.ShouldBe("Mr.Burns"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it exists now https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/MultipleAsserts.cs, after the issue [1920](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1920) got addressed. It is shipped first in the assert.xunit-tag [2.4.2-pre.19](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/releases/tag/2.4.2-pre.19) and the NuGet-package [assert.xunit 2.4.2-pre.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.assert/2.4.2-pre.12). See also [Release Notes of xUnit.net 2.4.2 Pre-Release (build 12)](https://xunit.net/releases/2.4.2-pre.12)

The example from the question could be written as

```cs
Assert.Multiple(
    () => Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult1, actualResult1, "Mismatch in Score1!"),
    () => Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult2, actualResult2, "Mismatch in Score2!"),
    () => Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult3, actualResult3, "Mismatch in Score3!"));
```